# Remove double quotes bounding rows in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have several improperly formatted csvs that are tab separated, but have a double-quote bounding each row. I can read them in and ignore the `"` with:

```r
library(data.table)
files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
dt = lapply(files, fread, sep="\t", quote="")
setattr(dt, 'names', gsub(".csv", "", files))
```

but is there a R `data.table` way of handling the quotes beyond separate commands to strip first and last columns?

```r
# sample table
DT = data.table(V1=paste0("\"", 1:5), V2=c(1,2,5,6,8), 
                V3=c("a\"","b\"","c\"","d\"","e\""))
dt = list(DT, DT, DT)

# these work but aren't using data.table 
dt = lapply(dt, function(i) {
  i[[1]] = gsub('"', '', i[[1]])
  i[[ncol(i)]] = gsub('"', '', i[[ncol(i)]])
  i
})

# magical mystery operation that doesn't work???
dt = lapply(dt, function(i){
    i[, .SD := gsub('"', '', rep(.SD)), .SDcols=names(i)[c(1, ncol(i))]]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either index or column names to assign

```
library(data.table)
lapply(dt, \(x) {
   # // get the column names based on the index 1st and last column
   nm1 <- names(x)[c(1, length(x))]
   # loop over the Subset of Data.table (.SD), use `gsub` 
   # after specifying the columns to select in .SDcols
   # assign the output back to the columns of interest (nm1)
   x[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = '"', replacement = ''), 
          .SDcols = nm1][]
 })
```

-output

```
[[1]]
       V1    V2     V3
   <char> <num> <char>
1:      1     1      a
2:      2     2      b
3:      3     5      c
4:      4     6      d
5:      5     8      e

[[2]]
       V1    V2     V3
   <char> <num> <char>
1:      1     1      a
2:      2     2      b
3:      3     5      c
4:      4     6      d
5:      5     8      e

[[3]]
       V1    V2     V3
   <char> <num> <char>
1:      1     1      a
2:      2     2      b
3:      3     5      c
4:      4     6      d
5:      5     8      e
```

---

Another option is `set`

```
lapply(dt, \(x) {
   
   nm1 <- names(x)[c(1, length(x))]
   for(j in nm1) set(x, i = NULL, j = j, value = gsub('"', '', x[[j]]))
 })
```

-output

```
dt
[[1]]
       V1    V2     V3
   <char> <num> <char>
1:      1     1      a
2:      2     2      b
3:      3     5      c
4:      4     6      d
5:      5     8      e

[[2]]
       V1    V2     V3
   <char> <num> <char>
1:      1     1      a
2:      2     2      b
3:      3     5      c
4:      4     6      d
5:      5     8      e

[[3]]
       V1    V2     V3
   <char> <num> <char>
1:      1     1      a
2:      2     2      b
3:      3     5      c
4:      4     6      d
5:      5     8      e
```